# AngularJS Sentence Builder similar to http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need angularjs solution (plugin or any fiddle/codepen etc. workaround) which is similar to query builders as below(which are available in github)

http://mfauveau.github.io/angular-query-builder/

or

http://niklr.github.io/angular-query-builder/

> NOTE: Before continueing the reading please look through 1st link
> alteast.

I should be able to form sentence with

```
operators: if, then, else, and, or, on
fields: xyzproduct, etc..
unit: quantity, value,..
conditions: =, <, <=, >, >=, <>, between
```

finally i should be able to form a promotion or discount kind of thing.

Output:

> (if xyzproduct quantity between 1 and 100) (then discount 10%)
>
> (if xyzproduct value > 500) (then discount 20%)

Comment: What have you tried? Please read the documentation on how to ask a question on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

http://niklr.github.io/angular-query-builder/

the above plugin you mentioned is good. this is more flexible to reach your requirement.